# find exact and similar name and return an array with preg_match

Tags: php, search, preg-match, similarity

everybody,

can someone please help with something.

I would like to search a list by name. As an example: Naruto

However, there are not only Naruto, but also "Naruto Shippuden" and "Boruto: Naruto Next Generations".

Now I want the other two to be displayed when the user searches for "Naruto".

```
<li><a href="#Naruto" title="Naruto">Naruto</a></li>
<li><a href="#Naruto-Shippuden" title="Naruto Shippuden">Naruto Shippuden</a></li>
<li><a href="#Boruto-Naruto-Next-Generations" title="Boruto: Naruto Next Generations">Boruto: Naruto Next Generations</a></li>
```

So far, I've tried that.

```
$re  = '/<li><a href=".*" title="(Naruto|(.*?))">(Naruto|(.*?))<\/a><\/li>/m';
$str = '<ul>
            <li><a href="serie/Boruto-Naruto-Next-Generations" title="Boruto: Naruto Next Generations">Boruto: Naruto Next Generations</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Masou-Gakuen-HxH" title="Masou Gakuen HxH">Masou Gakuen HxH</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Matantei-Loki-Ragnarok" title="Matantei Loki Ragnarok">Matantei Loki Ragnarok</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Mawaru-Penguindrum" title="Mawaru Penguindrum">Mawaru Penguindrum</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Nanbaka" title="Nanbaka">Nanbaka</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Narutaru" title="Narutaru">Narutaru</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Naruto" title="Naruto">Naruto</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Naruto-Shippuden" title="Naruto Shippuden">Naruto Shippuden</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Natsu-iro-Kiseki" title="Natsu-iro Kiseki">Natsu-iro Kiseki</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Natsume-Yuujinchou" title="Natsume Yuujinchou">Natsume Yuujinchou</a></li>
        </ul>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: So, did you try anything? Can you show us your attempts?

Comment: Cna you show your relevant code?

Comment: Where do your list come from? A database? hardcoded? In other words, to what should apply your search?

Comment: It's in an HTML file.
I have edited my post with my attempt.

Comment: Are you trying to match HTML with a regex? [This is slightly relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1531971) And we should never let a chance go by to post this answer. EVER.

Comment: I don't understand the Post.
I need a practical example to see how this is possible.
I thought Regex was the best way. How else can I search by name and display similar names?

Comment: Because HTML isn't regular. Attributes in tags can be in any order. There can be human errors (non closed tags in example). Tags can be nested etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise you to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) for your purpose, it's easy to use.

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

$str = '<ul>
            <li><a href="serie/Boruto-Naruto-Next-Generations" title="Boruto: Naruto Next Generations">Boruto: Naruto Next Generations</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Masou-Gakuen-HxH" title="Masou Gakuen HxH">Masou Gakuen HxH</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Matantei-Loki-Ragnarok" title="Matantei Loki Ragnarok">Matantei Loki Ragnarok</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Mawaru-Penguindrum" title="Mawaru Penguindrum">Mawaru Penguindrum</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Nanbaka" title="Nanbaka">Nanbaka</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Narutaru" title="Narutaru">Narutaru</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Naruto" title="Naruto">Naruto</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Naruto-Shippuden" title="Naruto Shippuden">Naruto Shippuden</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Natsu-iro-Kiseki" title="Natsu-iro Kiseki">Natsu-iro Kiseki</a></li>
            <li><a href="serie/Natsume-Yuujinchou" title="Natsume Yuujinchou">Natsume Yuujinchou</a></li>
        </ul>';

$htmlStr = str_get_html($str);

echo ('<ul>');
foreach ($htmlStr->find('a[title*="naruto"]') as $link) //find all link having the title attribute containing naruto
    echo ('<li>' . $link . '</li><br />');
echo ('</ul>');
```

Outputs as HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="serie/Boruto-Naruto-Next-Generations" title="Boruto: Naruto Next Generations">Boruto: Naruto Next Generations</a></li><br />
    <li><a href="serie/Naruto" title="Naruto">Naruto</a></li><br />
    <li><a href="serie/Naruto-Shippuden" title="Naruto Shippuden">Naruto Shippuden</a></li><br />
</ul>
```